# Use explicit path in intersection inside axis (pgfplots)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, intersections

I'm trying to achieve the following:
[image]

I know I can do that with help of `intersections` tikz library. However, the main requirement is to avoid any temporary paths (`\path[name path=t] (2,0) -- (2,\ymaxv);`) and name them somehow. In big projects it becomes messy.

Here are two my attempts that unfortunately doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis lines = center]
\def\ymaxv{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}}

\addplot[blue, name path global=x] {x};

% this doesn't work
\draw[red] (2,0) -- (intersection of {2,0--2,\ymaxv} and x);

% neither this does
\draw[red, name intersections={of={2,0--2,\ymaxv} and x}] (2,0) -- (intersection-1);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The first one (I know that is deprecated) doesn't see `x` path, but the other cannot work with `2,0--2,\ymaxv` path.

Comment: Why is it messy? Because you can't reuse path name? (define a macro that generates unique path name automatically?)

Comment: Could you elaborate your problem a bit more precise, please. Because e.g. if you have a _function_ and want to have a vertical line to the x-axis (as shown in the example) this could easily be done without the intersections library.

Comment: @StefanPinnow, yes, in general I want exactly what you described: having any x₀ coordinade, draw straight line from x-axis to the function. But I decided to simplify the question as much as I could.

Answer (score 2):

Here I present two possibilities to add vertical lines. For details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.18.1
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % use this `compat` level or higher so for TikZ commands axis coordinates
    % are used by default
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    /pgf/declare function={
        % define your function
        f(\x) = (\x)^2;
        % (optionally defines some constants so you only have *one* place where
        %  you need to change it)
        a = 3;
    },
]
    \begin{axis}[
        no markers,
    ]
        \addplot {f(x)};
        % to have vertical lines to y = 0 simply use `ycomb`
        % (and works for arbitrary `\addplot`s, i.e. also table data etc.)
        \addplot+ [ycomb,samples at={2}] {f(x)};
        % to have vertical lines to arbitrary y-values you can e.g. use TikZ commands
        \draw [green] (a, {f(a)}) -- (a, 20);
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: I guess it'll work in most of my scenarios, but what about arbitrary paths? Sometimes I have `to` path with `in=A,out=B` arguments or even `.. controls ...` for even more curly lines. Is there any other approach that avoids creating temporal paths?

Comment: So  now you are asking for arbitrary paths and not for known functions (any more). So the problem "reduces" to pure TikZ which then will also work in PGFPlots. Unfortunately I am not 100% sure if I have understood your question right. Therefore I suggest to ask a new [follow-up question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2117) and describe you problem in more detail (what "intersects" with what). Because I'll don't check pure TikZ questions, please ping me here again with a link to the new question. Then I'll have look.

Comment: I created one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/628207/213149

Comment: Sorry that I can't give a general answer, but at least for known functions you have one. So please consider [accepting this answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓) so it gets off the "unanswered list".

Comment: please don't treat me as ungrateful or rude, but the title of this question is about using explicit paths even though it's only an intermediate step for something greater I'm trying to achieve. So there is a chance, someone will respond to this the the exact answer. Otherwise, someone who's also interested in this specific question will be disappointed because "accepted answer" has nothing to do with using explicit paths.

Comment: Ok, to be more precise: I would change (at least) the title of the question so that it is related to explicit *functions* (as I have asked [in the comment below the question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/628045/use-explicit-path-in-intersection-inside-axis-pgfplots/628152?noredirect=1#comment1566510_628045). The *new* question is the general one. Otherwise one of both would be a duplicate of the other ... You could also add a link in the body of the question with your ultimate goal stated in the follow-up question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    
\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tzaxes(-5,-5)(5,5)
\tzticks*[black!40](-3pt:3pt){-4,-2,2,4}(-3pt:3pt){-4,-2,2,4}
\tzticks<-3pt,-3pt>{-4,-2,2,4}{-4,-2,2,4}
\def\Fx{\x}
\tzfn[blue,thick]\Fx[-5:5]
\tzvXpointat{Fx}{2}(X)
\tzprojx[red,solid,thick](X)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```