# Vertical line from each plotted point on another line

Tags: pgfplots

I have a plot that looks like this:

[image: my graph]

I want to achieve something like this in efficient way:

[image: graph I want]

As shown, I want vertical red bars or lines from each point on the straight line.

My code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=0,
            xmax=9.5,
            ymin=-5,
            ymax=105,
        ]
            \addplot[only marks] table [x=x_k,y=T_k]{
                x_k T_k
                1   15.6
                2   17.5
                3   36.6
                4   43.8
                5   58.2
                6   61.6
                7   64.2
                8   70.4
                9   98.8
            };
            \addplot[thick,black,domain=1:9,samples=1000]{4.8+9.41*x};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want perpendicular lines or vertical lines as shown on the picture?

Comment: Oh sorry, a horrible use of word I made. That should be vertical lines.

Comment: @SolidMark maybe this [solution by Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147414/163874) ?

Comment: @JeT, just like that. But I think my question is more simpler than the one you gave, so I think I am asking for a simpler solution since I have a table made and a line as per expression.

Comment: @SolidMark you might benefit from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/628152/163874)

Comment: Yeah, I managed to solve the problem with the help of that link and learning more about `pgfplotstable`